# libc.so crash on Android 12 devices

Tags: android, android-12

I found a strange crash message about the system so library on the APM platform, and it only happens on Android 12 devices.

Some of my app build gradle config:

```
compileSdkVersion 31
buildToolsVersion '31.0.0'
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 24
    targetSdkVersion 26

    ndk {  
        abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
    }
}
```

And below is the crash message:

```
Process Name: 'xxx'
Thread Name: 'ReferenceQueueD'
pid: 29245, tid: 29254  >>> com.xxx.xxxx <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00fffffefffffff0
  x0   00000070a0f4a6c0  x1   00ffffff00000000  x2   0000000000000000  x3   0000000000000000
  x4   0000000000000010  x5   0000006ded2d4340  x6   0003522200034d82  x7   00034dcc00035472
  x8   02ffffff00000000  x9   02ffffff00000000  x10  00000000ecc30e2f  x11  0000000000000000
  x12  0000000000000019  x13  000009f3ba83fe32  x14  00106e6d9f58a32d  x15  0000000034155555
  x16  00000070803f9248  x17  00000070a0eb2c00  x18  0000006d758cc000  x19  00ffffff00000000
  x20  0000000000000000  x21  00000070a0f4a6c0  x22  0000000000000000  x23  0000000014f28e78
  x24  000000006f7aaba0  x25  0000000014f28eb8  x26  0000000000000000  x27  0000006de9217000
  x28  0000000000000043  x29  0000006d7631b6e0  x30  00000070806b0cd0
  sp   0000006d7631b6d0  pc   00000070a0eb8668  pstate 0000000060001000
  v0   0000518400006498000050f0000035e9  v1   000030ff000055ff000052d100004c9a
  v2   00000000001c30000000006dd3dca000  v3   00000000000001000000000000000100
  v4   00000000000221c00000000000022180  v5   0000221c000022180000221400002210
  v6   00000000000000000000000000000000  v7   00000000000000008060180680601806
  v8   00000000000000000000000000000000  v9   00000000000000000000000000000000
  v10  00000000000000000000000000000000  v11  00000000000000000000000000000000
  v12  00000000000000000000000000000000  v13  00000000000000000000000000000000
  v14  00000000000000000000000000000000  v15  00000000000000000000000000000000
  v16  c0300c03c0300c03c0300c03c0300c03  v17  00000000000800000000080001000404
  v18  00000000000000000000080000000000  v19  0000000000000000be00000000000000
  v20  00000000000000003ff0002b8b263fc3  v21  00000000000001480000000000000001
  v22  00000000000000380000000000000001  v23  00000000000002000000000000000001
  v24  00000000000000800000000000000001  v25  00000000000001100000000000000001
  v26  00000000000001800000000000000001  v27  00000000000000b80000000000000001
  v28  00000000000000000000000300000001  v29  000000000000000c0000000000000002
  v30  00000000000000080000000000000002  v31  006d005f00790061006c00650064005f
  fpsr 00000010  fpcr 00000000
    #00 pc 0000000000006668  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (_ZN5scudo9AllocatorINS_13AndroidConfigEXadL_Z21scudo_malloc_postinitEEE10deallocateEPvNS_5Chunk6OriginEmm+104)
    #01 pc 0000000000121ccc  /apex/com.android.i18n/lib64/libicui18n.so (_ZN6icu_6812RegexPattern3zapEv+216)
    --- --- --- ---
```

This crash has not yet been reproduced on my test devices.It has been bothering me for a long time, I can't find relevant information on Google, and I am very eager for any relevant help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because it tried to access an illegal memory address (address  00fffffefffffff0).  It's illegal because that address isn't mapped to a valid space in virtual memory.  It's occurring in some memory management code-  notice the function name says malloc_postinit (malloc is the C function to request memory) dealocateChunk.

So either the C standard library has a bug in it (unlikely but possible), or somehow the memory of the allocation table got corrupted.  Which can happen if C code overwrites its bounds or if an already deallocated chunk of memory is written to by mistake. Or a few hardware causes (RAM failure, cosmic rays, etc).  Unless you can reliably reproduce it, you're not going to solve it.  If you can reproduce it, try to figure out what the corrupted memory was holding and look for illegal access to it.  A memory watch would work for that.  But really these kinds of problems are incredibly hard to track, especially when not writing C or C++ yourself, as the illegal access is likely occurring far from your code.